# Why can't I use my angular directive on a select element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onfocus

I have a directive to focus on fields in my application.

**focus-on directive**

```
module.exports = function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
      debugger;
        scope.$on('focusOn', function(e, name) {
            if (name === attr.focusOn) {
                elem[0].focus();
            }
        });
    };
};
```

It works on this inputfield:

```
<input type="text" focus-on="diameter" />
```

I can trigger it like this in controller:

```
$timeout(function() {
   $rootScope.$broadcast('focusOn', field);
});
```

But when I try to do the same on a select element in doesn't work:

```
<select focus-on="type"
        tabindex="{{item.layerId}}"
        ng-options="materialType.id for materialType in presetData.materialTypes track by materialType.id"
        ng-model="item.type"
        ng-change="materialTypeChanged(item.type)">
</select>
```

Why is it not working on my select element?

Comment: That's a strange way to define a directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) where did you learn that?

Comment: It should only work once, as you do `$rootScope.$broadcast('focusOn', field);` only 1 time.